# HighCharts Label horizontally instead of vertically on IE10 compatibility

Tags: highcharts, internet-explorer-10

In `Internet Explorer 10`, if you set the page to be `IE8 documents mode` does y-axis label appears horizontally instead of vertically?

We have controls what require us to use the IE8 mode on the page.

I've managed to get it to happen on my site and the `HighCharts` website too.
Is there a workaround for this?

Thanks

Comment: short answer: don't use compatibility mode. there's no reason to use it.

Comment: unless of course we didn't have other controls on the page that required it to be in a previous version?

Their website it is compatable with IE6 + so why shouldn't it work on IE8 compatability?

Comment: you didn't specify that in the question, but if that is the case, then I suggest you need to think about updating the other control.

Comment: There's an issue for it in the Highcharts GitHub repo: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1711. It applies only to IE10 with quirks mode, not native old IE.